# Pandas how to sort the connected string within every row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The sample data is :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d=pd.DataFrame({'lender':['tony','wood','tony','tidy'],
                'borrower':['wood','tony','wood','tony']})
```

[image]

I want to connect `lender` and `borrower` and most importantly sort them within each row. In a word, I want get P:

[image]

The sort principle is the same as the default `sorted` function. For example:

```
sorted(['tony','wood'])
Out[221]: ['tony', 'wood']

sorted(['wood','tony'])
Out[222]: ['tony', 'wood']
```

`apply` is preferred unless you have to use for loop.
Please read it clearly before you duplicate my question!!!

Comment: Are you sure my question is duplicate as the one you mentioned???

Comment: So you make my question as duplicate, but there is not any answer. Can you cancel you mark??? Or I need to ask this question again!!!

Comment: sorry, I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is use `apply` with sorted and `join` per each row:

```
d['p'] = d[['lender','borrower']].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(sorted(x)), axis=1)
print (d)
  lender borrower          p
0   tony     wood  tony_wood
1   wood     tony  tony_wood
2   tony     wood  tony_wood
3   tidy     tony  tidy_tony
```

Or use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with `DataFrame` constructor is performance is important:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(d[['lender','borrower']], axis=1))
d['p'] = d1[0] + '_' + d1[1]
print (d)
  lender borrower          p
0   tony     wood  tony_wood
1   wood     tony  tony_wood
2   tony     wood  tony_wood
3   tidy     tony  tidy_tony
```